# Google Cast button not showing in Android

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

Trying to use Google's cast SDK v3 in my project, the cast button is failing to appear even though I have cast receivers active near me

I have added the Google cast button to my project layout like so:

```
<android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
        android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:mediaRouteTypes="user"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

The button above is **NOT** a menu button, so I have setup the button in my onCreate like so:

```
CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(), mediaRouteButton);
```

I have also create the `CastOptionsProvider` and pointed to it in my `AndroidManifest` file

According to the Google cast docs:

> In v3, the discovery process is started and stopped automatically by
>   the framework when the app comes to the foreground and goes to the
>   background, respectively. MediaRouteSelector and MediaRouter.Callback
>   should not be used.

Any ideas why is the google cast button not appearing automatically since the button should handle his own state?

**EDIT**

My current solution/workaround is:

```
castContext.addCastStateListener(
    newState -> updateCastButtonVisibility(button, newState)
);

private static void updateCastButtonVisibility(View button, int state) {
 if (state == CastState.NO_DEVICES_AVAILABLE) {
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `android:visibility="visible"`?

Comment: @DanielZolnai The button should manage it's own visibility. start with gone, if there are receiver application available should become visible.

Comment: There could be a number of reasons why discovery doesn't work. Does the CastVideos sample app discover your receiver?

Comment: @TareKKhoury were you able to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So apparently this is a bug in the cast SDK.

I have opened a ticket for it and the Google cast team managed to reproduce it and accepted this bug.

Here is a link to the [reported bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73334497) so you can track it

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is that your application id does not exist yet.
The GoogleCast button doesn't show up is the application id is invalid.
You can test out the default id:

```
CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID
```